# Determining precisely ram unused available in Win32

Tags: windows, visual-c++, ram

I use this routine to fill unused ram with zero.
It procures crash on some computers and is coarse
size =  size - (size /10);
There is a more accurate way to determine the unused RAM amount to be filled with zeroes?

```
DWORDLONG getTotalSystemMemory(){
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS lMemInfo;
    BOOL success = GetProcessMemoryInfo(
        GetCurrentProcess(),
        &lMemInfo,
        sizeof(lMemInfo)
    ); 
    MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
    statex.dwLength = sizeof(statex);
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&statex);
    wprintf(L"Mem: %d\n", lMemInfo.WorkingSetSize);
    return statex.ullAvailPhys - lMemInfo.WorkingSetSize;
}

void Zero(){
    int size =  getTotalSystemMemory();//-(1024*140000)
    size =  size - (size /10);
    //if(size>1073741824) size=1073741824; //2^32-1
    wprintf(L"Mem: %d\n", size);
    BYTE* ar = new BYTE[size];
    RtlSecureZeroMemory(ar,size);
    delete[] ar;
}
```

Comment: The whole idea of doing this from userspace is ill-conceived.  You can't control what RAM blocks your buffer gets mapped into.  Pathologically, they could all be placed into the swapfile and cycled through a single page of RAM, one at a time, and no other page ever touched.

Comment: To learn more about memory management in windows examine [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533), [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229), Mysteries of Memory Management Revealed,with Mark Russinovich (Part [1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL405), [2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL406))

Answer (score 5):

This program does not do what you think it does. In fact, it is counterproductive. Fortunately, it is also unnecessary.

First of all, the program is unncessary Windows already has a thread whole sole job to zero out free pages, uncreatively known as the *zero page thread*. [This blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2010/10/29/pdc10-mysteries-of-windows-memory-management-revealed-part-two.aspx) goes into quite a bit of detail on how it works. Therefore, the way to fill free memory with zeroes is to do nothing because there is already somebody filling free memory with zeroes.

Second, the program does not do what you think it does because when an application allocates memory, the kernel makes sure that the memory is full of zeroes before giving it to the application. (If there are not enough pre-zeroed pages available, the kernel will zero out the pages right there.) Therefore, your program which writes out zeroes is just writing zeroes on top of zeroes.

Third, the program is counterproductive because it is not limiting itself to memory that is free. It is zeroing out a big chunk of memory that might have been busy. This may force other applications to give up their active memory so that it can be given to you.

The program is also counterproductive because even if it manages only to grab free memory, it dirties the memory (by writing zeroes) before freeing it. Returning dirty pages to the kernel puts them on the "dirty free memory" list, which means that the zero page thread has to go and zero them out again. (Redundantly, in this case, but the kernel doesn't bother checking whether a freed page is full of zeros before zeroing it out. Checking whether a page is full of zeroes is about as expensive as just zeroing it out anyway.)

It is unclear what the purpose of your program is. Why does it matter that free memory is full of zeroes or not?

Comment: I would like to reset all unused memory before hibernate the system.

Comment: Sure Hibernation does not save unused memory? i tryed to open a file with notepad, after i close the file. The file not use now memory. I hiberate system. Reboot and edit the hiberfil.sys and see in it the text content in the previous file read in notepad. If Hibernation does not save unused memory why it mantain text in file previous closed?

Comment: Um, it's in notepad's memory. Or the disk cache. Or in the file system driver's data structures. It can be in many places other than freed memory.

Comment: @user745759 Look at [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL406) webcast from 56:51 with secret.txt example. I've already [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124707/launch-zero-page-thread-programmaticaly#comment19554026_14124707) you use Rammap emty feature to reset standby list and learn [more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178918/determining-precisely-ram-unused-available-in-win32#comment19651888_14178918) about memory management in windows.

Comment: I use a disk cache in 1Mb tiny ramdisk. In not can reset the disk cache Or the file system driver's data structures for data unused? I not can to try Rammap on my xp. I do not understand why you can not find an easy way to reset the unused memory. for example run a "zero-page thread" on demand. or use a like RAMMap "Empty ..." feature via command line or programmatically in xp.

Comment: @RaymondChen I think the data is in standy list.

Comment: The problem is always similar : how do I reset the standy list? :) if the data is in standy list, then it is every unused ram, why not reset at hibernation? I'd love to see the webcast but English is not my mother tongue : (

Comment: @user745759 http://forum.sysinternals.com/rammap-empty-standby-list_topic27297.html source code + exe. Did you see example with secret.txt?

Comment: @user745759 Do not listen, just look :) 2 min from 56:51

Comment: @sergmat i know also this. It not work in xp RtlAcuquirePrivilege missing in ntdll.dll. And i'm not able to find the routine in the source code. What is "secret.txt"?

Comment: Regardless, any attempt to address this issue cannot be done from a user-mode program. You must do it from kernel mode. (It's also not clear even why you care.)